# strategy for WCF Mobile contract

Tags: wcf, mobile, soa, datacontract

Is there a clever way to structure my WCF service, such that I can implement a service once and have it return different data contracts for different callers? (i.e. mobile clients)

We have already developed a set of services which are consumed by a desktop application and are now building a mobile version of the application. The problem is that the data transfer objects (DTOs) returned are too big and contain unnecessary members for the mobile application. With it going over a mobile network we would like to cut these out to improve performance, however the implementation of the services will be identical.

Ideas we have so far:

- Setting
  EmitDefault to false and then not mapping all properties on the
  DTO for mobile callers (we are using automapper so may be able to do something
  with multiple mapping configurations)
- Inherited DTO types for desktop that extend the basic mobile type using the KnownType attribute.
- Just building a separate service entirely, but making sure all logic is in a shared business service layer (which it should be already)

Does anyone know if there is any guidance out there for this requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would keep the implementations separate. As you point out, each set of clients - mobile and desktop - have different requirements. You can share the contracts for your service, just have different implementations / services. This will allow to specialise the services for each client, and makes it easier to extend, modify and test.

Comment: Cheers for the response, the problem is that you can't actually share the contracts, because as well as the methods they also specify the data types. I was trying to avoid this situation if possible as it seems like a lot of repeated code to implement the same services twice, but just with different data transfer objects that have a subset of properties.

Comment: That is a bit of a dilemma. When you say "have a subset of properties" what do you mean? are the data contracts that you expose to a mobile application different?

Comment: Yes, the mobile application will use the same services, but just doesn't show as much information, so it only needs some of the properties from the data contracts. But for performance reasons we'd like to cut stop the extra data going over the wire rather than just ignore it on the client.

Comment: In that case I don't think you have much choice than to create a new data contract and service contract. You could try generics but that isn't going to be very interoperable.